# dimensional-tf: creating ordinary Int, Double, etc. values?

Tags: haskell

When using the [`dimensional-tf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-tf) package, is it possible to work with "ordinary" `Num` instances (i.e. `Int`, `Double`, `Integer`) without using the `one` unit?

For example, this code doesn't type check (in ghci):

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Numeric.Units.Dimensional.TF.Prelude
import qualified Prelude as P

fourpi = 4 * pi
```

but this code does:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Numeric.Units.Dimensional.TF.Prelude
import qualified Prelude as P

fourpi = (4 *~ one) * (pi *~ one)
```

Note: let me know if I should use `dimensional` instead of `dimensional-tf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dimensional` (and `dimensional-tf`) package hides the operators from `Num` and `Fractional` and defines operators with the same name, but different types. These operators don't work with unadorned number types.

So with

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Numeric.Units.Dimensional.TF.Prelude
import qualified Prelude as P
```

you can't just write

```
fourpi = 4 * pi
```

since `(*) :: Num a => Dimensional v d a -> Dimensional v d' a -> Dimensional v (Mul d d') a` then, and there are no `Num` instances for `Dimensional` types (there can't be, since the product of two dimensional types generally has a different dimension), thus `4` and `pi` cannot be interpreted as values of dimensional type.

You can, however, write

```
fourpi = 4 P.* P.pi
```

etc., the qualified versions of the operators from `Num` are still available.